# Android Custom ListPreference only allow 5 items

Tags: java, android, listpreference

Im creating a custom ListPreference on the back of [this](http://www.lucazanini.eu/2014/android/display-icon-preferences/#comment-29209) example.

I've implemented it and it works. But I can only add a max of 5 item to the ListPreference. If I add 7 items they appears in the list but when I click it it does nothing, just closes the ListPref dialog and return to the pref screen

```
public class IconPickerPreference extends ListPreference {

private class CustomListPreferenceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<IconItem> {

    private Context context;
    private List<IconItem> icons;
    private int resource;

    public CustomListPreferenceAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<IconItem> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.icons = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.iconName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.iconName);
            holder.iconImage = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.iconImage);
            holder.radioButton = (RadioButton) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.iconRadio);
            holder.position = position;

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.iconName.setText(icons.get(position).name);

        int identifier = context.getResources().getIdentifier(
                icons.get(position).file, "drawable",
                context.getPackageName());
        holder.iconImage.setImageResource(identifier);

        holder.radioButton.setChecked(icons.get(position).isChecked);

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
                for (int i = 0; i < icons.size(); i++) {
                    if (i == holder.position)
                        icons.get(i).isChecked = true;
                    else
                        icons.get(i).isChecked = false;
                }
                getDialog().dismiss();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

}

private static class IconItem {

    private String file;
    private boolean isChecked;
    private String name;

    public IconItem(CharSequence name, CharSequence file, boolean isChecked) {
        this(name.toString(), file.toString(), isChecked);
    }

    public IconItem(String name, String file, boolean isChecked) {
        this.name = name;
        this.file = file;
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
    }

}

private static class ViewHolder {
    protected ImageView iconImage;
    protected TextView iconName;
    protected int position;
    protected RadioButton radioButton;
}

private Context context;
private ImageView icon;

private CharSequence[] iconFile;
private CharSequence[] iconName;
private List<IconItem> icons;
private SharedPreferences preferences;
private Resources resources;
private String selectedIconFile, defaultIconFile;
private TextView summary;

public IconPickerPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;

    resources = context.getResources();
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.attrs_icon, 0, 0);

    try {
        defaultIconFile = a.getString(R.styleable.attrs_icon_iconFile);
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }
}

private String getEntry(String value) {
    String[] entries = resources.getStringArray(R.array.iconName);
    String[] values = resources.getStringArray(R.array.iconFile);
    int index = Arrays.asList(values).indexOf(value);
    return entries[index];
}

@Override
protected void onBindView(View view) {
    super.onBindView(view);

    selectedIconFile = preferences.getString(
            resources.getString(R.string.custom_icon_key), defaultIconFile);

    icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iconSelected);
    updateIcon();

    summary = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.summary);
    summary.setText(getEntry(selectedIconFile));

}

@Override
protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
    super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);

    if (icons != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < icons.size(); i++) {
            IconItem item = icons.get(i);
            if (item.isChecked) {

                Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString(
                        resources.getString(R.string.custom_icon_key),
                        item.file);
                editor.apply();

                selectedIconFile = item.file;
                updateIcon();

                summary.setText(item.name);

                break;
            }
        }
    }

}

@Override
protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(Builder builder) {

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    builder.setPositiveButton(null, null);

    iconName = getEntries();
    iconFile = getEntryValues();

    if (iconName == null || iconFile == null
            || iconName.length != iconFile.length) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "ListPreference requires an entries array "
                        + "and an entryValues array which are both the same length");
    }

    String selectedIcon = preferences.getString(
            resources.getString(R.string.custom_icon_key),
            resources.getString(R.string.icon_default));

    icons = new ArrayList<IconItem>();

    for (int i = 0; i < iconName.length; i++) {
        boolean isSelected = selectedIcon.equals(iconFile[i]) ? true
                : false;
        IconItem item = new IconItem(iconName[i], iconFile[i], isSelected);
        icons.add(item);
    }

    CustomListPreferenceAdapter customListPreferenceAdapter = new CustomListPreferenceAdapter(
            context, R.layout.item_picker, icons);
    builder.setAdapter(customListPreferenceAdapter, null);

}

private void updateIcon() {
    int identifier = resources.getIdentifier(selectedIconFile, "drawable",
            context.getPackageName());

    icon.setImageResource(identifier);
    icon.setTag(selectedIconFile);
}
```

String values

```
 <string-array name="iconName">
    <item>CHESTNUT</item>
    <item>POMEGRANATE</item>
    <item>OLD BRICK</item>
    <item>FLAMINGO</item>
    <item>SNUFF</item>
    <item>RAZZMATAZZ</item>
    <item>NEW YORK PINK</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="iconFile">
    <item>ic_chestnut</item>
    <item>ic_pomegranate</item>
    <item>ic_old_brick</item>
    <item>ic_flamingo</item>
    <item>ic_snuff</item>
    <item>ic_razzmatazz</item>
    <item>ic_new_york_pink</item>
</string-array>
```

7 ic_ pngs for the items above in drawable...

Logs not showing any index error...

Stumped :P

Any help appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem could be caused because you are saving the position in your ViewHolder, why do you do that?

Mark final the position field, and use it directly in your OnClickListener.

```
    @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   ... 

    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            for (int i = 0; i < icons.size(); i++) {
                if (i == position)
                    icons.get(i).isChecked = true;
                else
                    icons.get(i).isChecked = false;
            }
            getDialog().dismiss();
        }
```

Comment: I wanna kiss ya!...Cheers man...works great...need more reps to give you an up vote...will do when I can :)